# Agent trying to reach same position as other agents, instead start spinning in place

Tags: unity, ai

I create units in my game and have a rally point where they should walk to when created, like Age of Empires.

My problem is that since they compete for this position after a while, sometimes they end up doing this:

https://gfycat.com/decentquestionableandeancondor

https://gfycat.com/densehonoredgalapagosalbatross

As you can see one of the guys cant reach the rally point, so he starts rotating.

I realize this has to do with stopping distance, but no matter how high I set the stopping distance this eventually becomes a problem when there are many enough units. And if I set it too high they dont walk to the rally point at all, since its not THAT far from the building they spawn from.

Is there any way to manage this scenario? i.e just making him go as close as he can, and then stop?

My AI Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class BaseAi : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    [HideInInspector]
    public NavMeshObstacle obstacle;

    float sampleDistance = 50;

    Transform mTransform;

    private void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        obstacle = GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>();
        mTransform = transform;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        agent.avoidancePriority = Random.Range(agent.avoidancePriority - 10, agent.avoidancePriority + 10);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (agent.isActiveAndEnabled && agent.hasPath)
        {
            var projected = agent.velocity;
            projected.y = 0f;

            if (!Mathf.Approximately(projected.sqrMagnitude, 0f))
                mTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(projected);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the position is a valid pathfinding position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">The position to sample.</param>
    public bool SamplePosition(Vector3 point)
    {
        NavMeshHit hit;
        return NavMesh.SamplePosition(point, out hit, sampleDistance, NavMesh.AllAreas);
    }

    public bool SetDestination(Vector3 point)
    {
        if (SamplePosition(point))
        {
            agent.SetDestination(point);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Teleport(Vector3 point)
    {
        agent.Warp(point);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return true if agent reached its destination
    /// </summary>
    public bool ReachedDestination()
    {
        if (agent.isActiveAndEnabled && !agent.pathPending)
        {
            if (agent.remainingDistance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                if (!agent.hasPath || agent.velocity.sqrMagnitude == 0f)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void ToggleObstacle(bool toggleOn)
    {
        agent.enabled = !toggleOn;
        obstacle.enabled = toggleOn;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (agent == null) { return; }
        if (agent.path == null) { return; }

        Color lGUIColor = Gizmos.color;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        for (int i = 1; i < agent.path.corners.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawLine(agent.path.corners[i - 1], agent.path.corners[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where and how often do you call BaseAI.SetDestination?

Comment: @DMGregory When a unit is finished being constructed (Think RTS), I call `SetDestination` once, using that specific buildings rally point.

The rally point is a set point +- random point inside a 5 unit radius. This way they dont try to go to the exact same point, but that only helps when building a few units. Not when building as many as in the edited GIF.

Comment: @DMGregory I suspect it occurs when they end up not reaching their destination, or when they are being pushed away from their destination. I.e they never stop trying to reach their destination (which makes sense cus I never tell them to), but not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is strat I could think of:

- Check that agent must gradually get closer to final destination. If he cannot get closer, maybe for about T duration, we will judge that he cannot progress anymore.
- But only check this only if when agent is moving toward "Final Destination", not in between path nodes.

---

### 1. Check if agent cannot progress more

Just simple check if distance could not get closer. With give up timer. These variables for checking are reset on starting new movement.

```
float m_LastDistanceToTarget;
float m_GiveUpTimer;
bool m_WillGiveUpAgent;
const float DefaultGiveUpTime = 1.0f;

void LateUpdate()
{
    if( agenthasPathAndAgentIsRunning )
    {
        float currentDistance = Vector3.Distance( transform.position, agent.destination );
        if( currentDistance < m_LastDistanceToTarget )
        {
            // Agent is getting closer, this is we want to see, go on, also reset give up time
            m_LastDistanceToTarget = currentDistance;
            m_GiveUpTimer = DefaultGiveUpTime;
        }
        else
        {
            // Cannot proceed closer, countdown time to giveup
            m_GiveUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if( m_GiveUpTimer <= 0 )
                m_WillGiveUpAgent = true;
        }
    }
}

public bool SetDestination(Vector3 point)
{
    if (SamplePosition(point))
    {
        agent.SetDestination(point);

        m_LastDistanceToTarget = float.PositiveInfinity;
        m_GiveUpTimer = DefaultGiveUpTime;
        m_WillGiveUpAgent = false;
        return true;
    }
}

public bool ReachedDestination()
{
    if (agent.isActiveAndEnabled && !agent.pathPending)
    {
        if( m_WillGiveUpAgent ) return true;
        /* Remaining is Omitted */
    }
}
```

### 2. Make above check only run on final corner

This 2nd check is to prevent "false give up" when agent is on complex navigation path because its distance to final position could goes up and down hence we cannot perform 1st check while in this condition.

[image]

When NavMeshAgent has path computed, it will has `agent.path.corners` and also [`agent.steeringTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-steeringTarget.html) which point to corner (in path) it is trying to move to. If steeringTarget becomes last index of path.corners, this mean agent is on last straight line to destination.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if( agenthasPathAndAgentIsRunning )
    {
        // Agent must be on last index corner
        // PS. Not 100% sure, verify this yourself
        if( agent.steeringTarget == agent.path.corners[lastIndex])
            /* First check code */
```

---

### Final Note

- Code is for simplicity, some variable is left to reader's work and check such as Vector3.Distance is expensive, optimize it if you do care.
- There could still be false positive with this check. [If large amount of agent move in group](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9Otw12OUvE), (plus all of your units are solid) some unit might temporary got obstructed by its moving friends and this could will falsely give up the agent. That would be another challenge to solve.

Comment: I can not test this for a few days but ur logic seems sound so Ill accept.

Comment: This works as intended except the exact scenario you describe "There could still be false positive with this check. If large amount of agent move in group, (plus all of your units are solid) some unit might temporary got obstructed by its moving friends and this could will falsely give up the agent. That would be another challenge to solve."

Comment: @Majs that would be good news, cheers. I just speculated that such case could happen  in future, maybe if there is unit with different speed (Heavy infantry) and normal one walking in group together. etc.

Comment: Yeah. The issue occurs if I have a large clump of units and I want to move them somewhere, the ones in the middle of the clump cant move until the outer units have moved out of the way. Meaning ur code will trigger and they will think they reached their destination. Not sure how to solve it actually...

Comment: I could think of: add simple distance check, as third condition, dont giveup until near N meters to target. (But that could take us to original problem, uh oh). Or If you willing to relax/change the game design: Units are not solid when moving, think of C&C, Starcraft. They will reach final target but then try to disperse itself to find free space then enable solid again. Watch these game footage for more idea, etc.

Comment: yeah distance check wont work just like u said. I also tried more Starcraft style movement, only problem with that is if I have a bunch of solid units with obstacle avoidance standing around, and a group of units with no obstacle avoidance comes through, that moving group will push the standing group freely, looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheap little trick you can use:

```
Vector3 lastPosition;

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (agent.isActiveAndEnabled && agent.hasPath)
    {
        Vector3 effectiveVelocity = (transform.position - lastPosition)/Time.deltaTime;

        effectiveVelocity.y = 0f;

        if (effectiveVelocity.squareMagnitude > 0.5f) // Tune this threshold to your needs.
            mTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(effectiveVelocity);
    }

    lastPosition = transform.position;
}
```

Here, instead of asking the agent which direction it *wants* to *try* to move, we look at our position history to find out which way we *have actually* moved. If we've stayed in pretty much the same spot, we don't visibly turn the unit.

That way, even if the underlying path planning is hesitating back and forth, the player only sees the agent turn when it successfully finds a new path and makes real progress.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Ahh, your first example showed an agent literally turning in place, so I aimed to fix that problem. This example more clearly shows your real problem: the agents make progress in a direction, but not very much before they turn around again.